# web2py - is it possible to import content of menu.py from another file?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, web2py

I have a `menu.py` which contains all my menus. 
I would like to use the `menu.py` file and in case someone from another team needs to add additional sub-menus they can add them on their own file, then `import menu.py` as well.

for example: i have 2 sub-menus under /models/menu.py:

system_sub_menu = [
...               ....
...               ....
]

file_sub_menu = [
...               ...
...               ...
]

Can i separate them into 2 files?

Thanks 
Yaron

Comment: try to provide an example of your previous efforts in doing that

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. First, you can put the two sets of items in two different files in the `/models` folder. Model files are executed in alphabetical order, so you can put together the final `response.menu` object in the second of the two files (any variables defined in the first model file will be available globally in the second file, without any need to import).

Alternatively, you can put one of the sub-menus in a module (in the `/modules` folder) and simply import it where needed.